# Oracle SQL report generation without null

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, nvl

My query:

```
SELECT s.artist_id AS ArtistID,
       s.name AS Song,
       at.name AS artistname,
       a.name AS Albumname
  FROM album s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN song a ON s.id = a.album_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN artist at ON at.id = s.artist_id;
```

null in song and album table

for above query after joining the tables there is null in report
(demo result)

Actual result

```
A B     
1 2                                                        
3
```

Expected result

```
A B                                   
1 2                                                  
3 *
```

I want to print the above result in excel instead of null it should be replaced with any character. Could you pls help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `NVL` function, e.g.

```
nvl(a.name, '*') as albumname
```

Or, `DECODE` might help:

```
decode(a.name, null, '*', a.name) as albumname
```

Or `CASE`:

```
case when a.name is null then '*'
     else a.name
end as albumname
```

Comment: "The ISO/ANSI standard function for this is `COALESCE()`:"

Answer (score 2):

The ISO/ANSI standard function for this is `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT a.artist_id AS ArtistID,
       a.name AS Song,
       COALESCE(ar.name, '*') AS artistname,
       COALESCE(s.name, '*') AS Albumname
FROM album a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     song s
     ON a.id = d.album_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     artist ar
     ON ar.id = a.artist_id;
```

Notice that I changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table names.